On Suzuki 2-groups being 2-Sylow subgroups
$\DeclareMathOperator\Sz{Sz}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Recall the definition of the finite Suzuki 2-groups: These are finite non-abelian 2-groups that contain more than one involution such that a solvable group of automorphisms permutes the involutions transitively. The Suzuki 2-groups were classified by Higman in Suzuki 2-groups.
According to Higman's classification, there are 4 types of Suzuki 2-groups labeled by A, B, C and D.
It is known that Suzuki 2-groups of Type A is isomorphic to a Sylow 2-subgroup of $\Sz(q)$ and that certain type of Suzuki 2-groups of Type B is isomorphic to a Sylow 2-subgroup of $\SU_3(q)$ where $q$ is a power of $2$.
My question is: Do Suzuki 2-groups of type C and D appear as Sylow 2-subgroups of some finite groups of lie type?

If a Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of a (non-Abelian) finite simple group $G$ is a Suzuki $2$-group, then it is certainly the case that every involution of $S$ is central in $S$. Hence $A = \Omega_{1}(Z(S))$, the subgroup generated by the involutions of $Z(S)$, is the same as $\Omega_{1}(S)$, the subgroup of $S$ generated by its involutions. Thus $A$ is strongly closed in $S$ with respect to $G$, that is to say $A^{g} \cap S \leq A$ for all $g \in G$.
Finite groups with a strongly closed Abelian $2$-subgroup were classified by D. Goldschmidt. In particular, he proved that a (non-Abelian) finite simple group with such a subgroup either has Abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup (which does not occur in the context of this question), or else has a $BN$-pair of rank one (and characteristic $2$). By Bender's theorem on groups with a strongly embedded subgroup, the only simple groups with a non-Abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup which can occur are ${\rm Sz}(q)$ or ${\rm PSU}_{3}(q)$ where $q \geq 4$ is a power of $2$. So it seems that Suzuki groups of type $C$ and $D$ do not occur as Sylow $2$-subgroups of finite simple groups.

I don't understand the part of Bender's theorem. Do you mean that "if a finite simple group $G$ has a Suzuki 2-group as its Sylow 2-subgroup, then $G$ has a strongly embedded subgroup"? Could you please explain more on this?

Yes, that is a consequence of  Goldschmidt's theorem, I was just trying to outline the argument.

In any finite group $G$ whose Sylow $2$-subgroup is a Suzuki $2$-group, the normalizer of the Sylow controls fusion. That should be enough to eliminate almost all groups of Lie type at a stroke?

Yes, that gets you to Lie rank 1 immediately. Goldschmidt' theorem is pre CFSG, and more general than need for this question.

@DavidA.Craven : It falls out of Goldschmidt's proof, but how do you see directly that $N_{G}(S)$ controls fusion when $S$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup? I see that $N_{G}(\Omega_{1}(Z(S))$ controls fusion, which still is enough to get you to Lie rank 1 using Alperin's  fusion theorem (or a suitable form thereof), so what you say is definitely correct, but did you have a shorter argument in mind?

@GeoffRobinson It is immediate from a result on fusion systems by Michael Aschbacher, and done on p9 of my paper with Adam Glesser. https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.1639.

Ah, OK, I must have seen your paper with Adam, but did not remember it. I'd have to look up Aschbacher's argument.
